# How to stop a loop from resetting?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When generate id button is pushed once, it will disable. and the numbers will display. the last 4 digits "0001" is a loop, meaning if I didn't disable the generate id button, the last 4 digits will add 1 to the end "0002" if I were to click on the button again. For now it is disabled because I only want the user to be able to generate that once..But when I push on the submit button, my codes run and the page resets (meaning the generate ID is now available to push). So when I push the generate ID button again it the loop is reset again, meaning it displays "0001" again but not "0002". What suggestions may I have to where when I push the submit button, the loop won't reset?

[image]

```
var count = 0;
function counter() {
    if (document.getElementById("generateid").onclick) {
        count++;
        return count;
    }

}

    function padDigits(number, digits) {
        return Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
    }
 function generateID() {


        if (document.getElementById("generateidtxt").value == "") {
            var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
            TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator();
            document.getElementById("generateid").disabled = true;
        }

}
 function guidGenerator() {
    var theID = (Year() + "-" + Month() + "-" + Day() + "-" + padDigits(counter(),4));
    return theID;
}

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Onclick = "Button1_Click" 
            OnClientClick = "javascript:return SubmitForm();" 
            Text="Submit" Width="98px"
/>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code as well?

Comment: shouldn't the server-side be in charge of handling the id in some way ?

Comment: You need to include your code.

Comment: data persistence = cookies or localStorage or File api... i may forgot other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the server! There is no way for the client with multiple browsers to know what the next value is. The server should be generating the number not the client side!

Comment: Now that I have seen your code I completely agree with epascarello, use the server to generate the ID, however you do that, use the server!  See my answer for a possible path to consider.

Comment: Okay.. thanks. could you point me in the right direction on what to do server sided to get the same concept?

Comment: The id should be built on the server, not the client and should be done when the form is submitted. Basically you want to add a row and build the id based off the index. If the id is needed by the person entering the data, the success page can give them that id.

Answer (score 0):

So without seeing your code, could I float the idea of using a database ID as your last four digits? What I am advocating is an initial save of a record in the database that has the sole purpose of getting the ID of the soon to be new record and then using the date prepended to the ID value. This will allow for your IDs to be unique and not "reset" to zero when the "loop" is restarted. This of course has the downside of creating a partial record in the database if and when the user does not submit the form.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is postback when you click submit button if your javascript function SubmitForm() return true it goes to to server side for Button1_Click event and after that your page will be reset.
To resolve this problem you can use **updatepanel and out asyncpostback** event for Submit button **or** you can do all your **generateID logic code on code behind side and store in viewstate**